# Mongodb java spring update nested object

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Running a java spring project (v2) with mongo v4.
Trying to update a nested object and been reading a lot on SO but havent found any good solution.

I have something like the following:

```
menu {
   id
   name
   categories {
     id
     name
     products {
       id
       price
       referenceProduct {
         id
         name
       }
     }
   }
}
```

When I update a reference product, then I want all my referenceproducts in menus to be updated as well.

I have tried the following:

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria
      .where("menuProductCategories.menuProducts.refProduct.id").is(refProduct.getId())
    );

Update update = new Update().set("menuProductCategories.$.menuProducts.$.refProduct", refProduct);
```

But then I get the too many positional elements found.

Next idea would be to use arrayfilters using something like the following (just trying to update name prop to 'TEST'):

```
Bson filter = Filters.eq("menuProductCategories.menuProducts.refProduct.id", new ObjectId(refProduct.getId()));
Bson update = new Document("$set", new Document().append("menuProductCategories.$[i].menuProducts.$[j].refProduct.name", "TEST"));
```

But then I get stuck on how to specify my arrayfilters since they all assume that you know the index, which I don't since I want to do a full search and update all that matches my initial criteria.

Any ideas? Of course I could just retrieve all the menus and iterate over them, but I would love to find a small neat solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below query in 3.6 server version with 3.6.x mongodb driver.

```
 MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection("col");

 Bson update = Updates.set("menuProductCategories.$[].menuProducts.$[i].refProduct.name", "TEST");
 Bson filter = Filters.eq("i.refProduct.id", new ObjectId(refProduct.getId()));
 UpdateOptions updateOptions = new UpdateOptions().arrayFilters(Arrays.asList(filter));

 collection.updateOne(null, update, updateOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it worked but I had to set a filter for the first parameter in UpdateOne.
It crashes when I want to replace the whole object:
`Bson update = Updates.set("menuProductCategories.$[].menuProducts.$[i].refProduct", refProduct);`

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Yw. do you see any error when it crashes ? Is it on application  side or mongo side ?

Comment: `org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class se.a.b.model.RefProduct`
I guess it somehow needs to know that it is a refproduct? Do I need the object to bson?

Comment: Try registering the pojo codec( in 3.5.x driver ) and see if it gets picked up. Something like `CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
              CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(db).withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);` More [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/)

Comment: Tried that but it didnt work, same problem. I think it has some problem to replace the refProduct since it is inside another object (Menu), it would probably work if it was in a RefProduct Collection.